# If function on datatables

Tags: javascript, datatable

```
    function sortfuction(selected) {
            var id = selected.value;
                if (id=0) {
                    $('#password-table').DataTable( {
                    "destroy": true,
                    "paging": false,
                    "searching":false,
                    "order": [[ id, "asc" ],]
                } );
                }
                }else{
                    $('#password-table').DataTable( {
                    "destroy": true,
                    "paging": false,
                    "searching":false,
                    "order": [[ id, "dsc" ],]
                }
        </script>
   <table id="password-table" class=" row-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
    <select id="selectorID" onchange="sortfuction(this)">
        <option value="1" >Count</option>
        <option value="0">ABC</option>
    </select>
```

Having this code, I want to be able to sort tables depending on what value is chosen on Select element. For instance, if ABC is chosen, I want my first datatable column to be sorted in ascending order, while if chosen Cound, I want my second column to be sorted descending order. At this point console returns

> Unexpected token 'else'

Comment: You have an extra ` }` before your else statement, just delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `}` before your else statement, just delete it . But you're also missing an `)` and another `}` after your else and another `}` to close the function. Also your if statement needs a double equals or triple equals `==` to test for equalliing a value otherwise it's just an assignment.

Also a quick look at the docs show it should be 'desc' not 'dsc' to sort descending. I have updated the code

so

```
function sortfuction(selected) {
        var id = selected.value;
            if (id==0) {
                $('#password-table').DataTable( {
                "destroy": true,
                "paging": false,
                "searching":false,
                "order": [[ id, "asc" ]]
            } );

            }else{
                $('#password-table').DataTable( {
                "destroy": true,
                "paging": false,
                "searching":false,
                "order": [[ id, "desc" ]]
            })
            }
  }
```

Comment: I have removed those. Now console returns Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: I realised I was missing one more for closing the function. I've also updated the code to use 'desc' instead of 'dsc'. There was also extra commas you did not need as part of the order parameter

Comment: Glad that worked, feel free to accept the answer if it's solved your issue